# Is there a difference between starting a WebLogic Admin Server through the command-line or through the Node Manager?

Tags: java, weblogic

I have WebLogic 11g installed on my machine under `/srv/wls`, and I start Node manager on it with `/srv/wls/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh`.

I create my domain with `config.sh`, and then I want to start the Admin Server of that domain with Node Manager. So I open a `WLST` session and do the following:

```
> nmConnect(...)
> nmStart('AdminServer')
```

But when I then visit `localhost:7001/console`, and login, the screen on the browser remains blank and the server logs tell me the server has run out of PermGen space.

I don't encounter this problem when starting the Admin Server through the shell script under `$DOMAIN/startWebLogic.sh`. Then it works fine.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I couldn't find anything in Google nor on the Oracle forums...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that nmStart doesn't pass any arguments to the child JVM process and the defaults don't have enough memory. Try adding the following:

```
# Start the Admin Server
arg = "Arguments=\" -server -Xms192m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xrs\""
prps = makePropertiesObject (arg)
nmStart('AdminServer', props=prps)
```

This is an annoyingly common problem that Oracle/BEA seems to not want to fix or to document properly.